# Acts_as_tree - one-to-Many: Show Records associated with children on parent page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, acts-as-tree

I have a relatively simple one-to-many relationship and use acts_as_tree to get it organized in the view. It kinda looks like this:

**Root**

```
  |_Product 1
  |_Product 2
  |_Category 1.1

        |_Product 3
        |_Product 4
        |_Category 1.1.1

               |_Product 5
```

The way I set it up is that I list products in the 'show' action of the category.
However I can't seem too figure out how to show: Product 1-5 in the 'show' for Category 1, Product 3-5 in Category 1.1 and so on ...

Does anyone have a hint, from where I can pick it up?

Thanks!
Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also have a look at the recent [ancestry](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem designed for high performance when one needs to get all the descendants in one SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using awesome_nested_set (recommended, I do), then you can do this:

If Product belongs_to Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    def products_in_tree
        Product.all(:joins => :category, :conditions => ['categories.lft >= ? and categories.rgt <= ?', left, right])
    end
end
```

If Product has_and_belongs_to_many Category (or has_many :through), change the :join to :categories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a nested set if you want solve this with acceptable performance (that is, avoid a multitude of separate database lookups to compile the list).

Rails used to have acts _ as _ nested_set built-in, and the [explanation of how it works](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/NestedSet/ClassMethods.html) is still very good and quite valid. Today you must use this as a [plugin](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set).

However, the default Rails plugin is not very good, which is why several other plugins has been made. I will recommend that you use [Awesome Nested Set](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/), which I have used myself with satisfying results.

Nested sets can be a bit hard to understand, but hopefully the first link and the other readme's will explain it to you.